# Можно ли в pygame покрасить заголовок окна

Tags: python, pygame

Можно ли покрасить в pygame заголовок окна с названием, указанный стрелкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: нет, pygame не имеет отношения к окну, да он его создает но с помощью системного API которое и отвечает за внешний вид окна, оно будет таким же как и все другие(стандартные) окна в системе.

Comment: Никак не поменять, советую воспользоваться библиотекой PyQt, через нее можно настроить внешний вид окна и заголовка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, изменить цвет заголовка окна в pygame вы не можете.

**Но:**

Вы можете убрать заголовок окна. Просто создавать `screen`
надо вот так:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(<ВЫСОТА>, <ШИРИНА>), pygame.NOFRAME)
                                                    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

А далее, как вам надо рисуете собственную рамочку.